# iptables do not work, very slow to process on Debian 8

Tags: debian, iptables

I never had issues with Debian 7 using iptables. However, with Debian 8, I cannot get iptables to work at all.

Simple script like this takes several minutes to load and can't access my portal page.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Delete existing rules
iptables -F

# Set default chain policies
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

# Loopback
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Outbound DNS
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT

# Portal
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 8443 -j ACCEPT

# Logging
iptables -N LOGGING
iptables -A INPUT -j LOGGING
iptables -A LOGGING -m limit --limit 12/min -j LOG --log-prefix "eh: " --log-level 7
iptables -A LOGGING - DROP
```

I get a bunch of iptable logs that can't access port 8443. I have 3 NIC's on the server, all virtual from ESXi 6.0. Without iptables, I can access the web, visit portal page, etc. No issues.

I tried specifying the eth0 in the iptables and that didn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

you are not adding rule for NEW , RELATED,ESTABLISHED . in previous version it may be it was allowing by default without adding or you have added. in this case you have to add rule .
first delete all rule using :

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
```

then add rule :

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

and run your script . it will work if not then put output of `sudo iptables -vnL`

Comment: Hmm, let me try adding the state to each line and see if that helps.

Comment: Made no difference

Comment: try to put option  NEW , ESTABLISHED , RELATED with iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT

Comment: check your gateway is ok .  do debugging like first remove drop output rule and check . also try to refresh page and see no. packet is increasing or not on port 8443  in command " iptables -vnL " if yes , then your connection request is coming to server but it is not responding . iptables   is very critical topic many problem occurs . best of luck

Comment: Got it working. I realized I had two gateways setup.